# ubuntu boot issue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 13.10, bootloader

So I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 x64 on my laptop that already has Windows 7 x64 (a dual boot installation) and after restarting my laptop i get the following message.

```
error: no such partition
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> _
```

Most of the solutions talk about deleting or when uninstalling Ubuntu this and this happened. I have used the same ubuntu.iso on my desktop and it works just fine (also dual boot). I tried most the solutions I've seen like re-installing GRUB. Please help me out, i want to use both Ubuntu and Win7.

Comment: boot `ubuntu live cd`,install `gparted` software,upload gparted screenshot to `imgur.com` and post the link here.

Answer (score 0):

you could boot with a usb drive and try to repair it with boot-repair
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair